# Obter formato em que arquivo de texto foi escrito no FORTRAN

Tags: arquivo, formatação, fortran

Olá,
Preciso fazer um programa que leia de um arquivo de entrada que possui linhas de texto escritas em formatos específicos e processe as informações lidas de forma a criar um arquivo de saída com alguns dados de interesse.
Conheço todos os formatos utilizados para escrever o arquivo de entrada (estão descritos em um arquivo de formatos), porém os dados em si são escritos nele por um outro programa, de forma "aleatória". Algumas linhas são fáceis de identificar (cabeçalhos e marcações de final de tabela, etc) outras não. Seria muito mais fácil se de alguma forma o FORTRAN fosse capaz de identificar o formato em que cada linha lida do arquivo de entrada foi escrita (por exemplo: '(1X,I5,3F8.1,2(5A,1X))'). Assim eu poderia apenas comparar o formato da linha com um dos formatos da lista que possuo e extrair quase que diretamente os dados necessários, por exemplo sabendo que o formato da linha lida e armazenada na variavel LINHA está descrito na variavel FORMATO, poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
IF (FORMATO='(1X,I5,3F8.1,2(5A,1X))') THEN
  READ(LINHA,'(6X,F8.1)') minha_variavel
END IF
```

Porque pode haver outro formato de linha lida tal como:

```
'(6A, 2F8.1, F8.6,2 (6A))'
```

Que se eu usar o mesmo comando READ acima, terei uma variável F8.1 escrita em "minha_variavel", mas esse não será o valor que eu queria.

Alguém sabe se o FORTRAN possui uma função que faça algo parecido (obter o formato em que uma linha de arquivo de texto foi escrita)? Se sim, qual a função?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema resolvido usando uma mistura de algumas das sugestões postadas no stack em inglês.
Li cada uma das linhas do arquivo de entrada numa variável interna (RLIN) no formato '(A165)'. Depois disso, li todo o conteúdo da string que coloquei nessa variável interna em diversas variáveis dummy, utilizando o formato que conhecia das linhas de onde queria tirar algumas informações (ler todas as informações da linha no formato desejado e ter a leitura com IOSTAT = 0 me garante que esta é a linha correta), então, caso o resultado da leitura for ok (IOSTAT = 0), é porque a linha que acabei de ler era a correta para as informações que queria, então armazeno o conteúdo de algumas das variáveis dummy em variáveis que representam os valores que me interessam. No código, a solução ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
OPEN(UNIT=LU1,FILE=RlinName,STATUS='OLD')
ilin = 0
formato = '(14X,A,1X,F7.1,1X,F7.1,5X,A,1X,A,1X,A,5X,A,I5,1X,A,I3,3F8.1,A,A,A,1X,A,2(1X,F8.2),1X,A,1X,A)'
DO WHILE (.TRUE.)
  READ(LU1,'(A165)',END=300) RLINFILE
  READ(RLINFILE,formato,IOSTAT=linhaok) dum2_a1,dum2_f1,dum2_f2,dum2_a2,dum2_a3,dum2_a4,dum2_a5,dum2_i1,dum2_a6,dum2_i2,dum2_f3,dum2_f4,dum2_f5,dum2_a7,dum2_a8,dum2_a9,dum2_a10,dum2_f6,dum2_f7,dum2_a11,dum2_a12
  IF(linhaok.EQ.0) THEN
    ilin = ilin+1
    rlin_lshu(ilin) = dum2_a4
    rlin_nbpa(ilin) = dum2_i1
    rlin_ncir(ilin) = dum2_i2
    rlin_ppij(ilin) = dum2_f3
    rlin_pqij(ilin) = dum2_f4
    rlin_tapn(ilin) = dum2_a7
  END IF
END DO
300 CLOSE(UNIT=LU1)
```

Comment: Mais detalhes na conversa no Stack em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563865/is-there-a-way-to-compare-the-format-in-which-a-line-of-a-text-file-was-written/48572692#48572692